# After installing package with pip from git repo, how to determine exact commit being installed?

Tags: python, git, pip

I have a project which depends on certain Python package which in turn is installed from github repo.
This is done using pip url like this: `git+ssh://git@github.com/user/project#egg=project_name`
I would like to determine which commit of that dependency project was actually fetched during installation. Especially important for autotest suite.
So, is there a way to either determine which commit is already installed, or to print commit being installed during installation?

P.S. I know I can use `--editable` installation mode in which case pip will keep a copy of the repo, and I then will be able to check version from that copy. But is it possible to achieve what I need without using this installation mode?